# ZipArchive can't unzip a larger zip file on the Device (ipad)?

Tags: ios

ZipArchive can't unzip a larger zip file on the Device (ipad)? It works on the simulator, but doesn't on the iPad. The zip file is about 60MB.

It doesn't show any error message and just returns 0 (use UnzipFileTo method)

Comment: It's very strange, somethings it works, but sometimes doesn't.